# Issue when trying to register an app for consent screen in google oauth

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-openid

I am trying to register my app for Oauth consent screen, so that I can create a  OAuth client ID. I keep getting this validation error at end of the form, even though I have submitted everything correctly.

> An error occurred while saving your app

And this error does not state which input in the form is invalid. Also in the network tab of development tools window, everytime I submit the request, I can see a POST request being initiated and it fails with following error.

> `{"error":{"code":3,"message":"The request failed because one of the field of the resource is invalid.","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure","violations":[{"type":"client_auth_config","subject":"?error_code=9&error_field_name=UpdateBrandWithMaskRequest.brand_id&error_field_value=0"}]}]}}.`

Any suggestions on how to fix this is highly appreciated. I have contacted the google support about this issue as well, but as of now they're saying everything works on their end and clear cache and cookies but it doesn't work. I have attached here a capture of consent config wizard I'm using as well.

[image: I have attached here a capture of consent config wizard I'm using as well.]

Comment: Can you verify if your user have the `Oauth Consent Creator` Role and the `Oauth Creator` Role ?

Comment: I am using the owner account for the project to create consent screen, so I assume I have the necessary permissions.

Comment: Check your emails for any message from Google, especially from `Trust & Safety` team. If the team sent an email requesting more information from you, your validation can be suspended. Verify your spam-box.

Comment: I have checked no emails, support case is still ongoing, no resolutions.

Comment: HI , Did you get any solution on that? ,I am facing same error that "An error saving your app has occurred".

Comment: Hi there, I'm also having the same issue. Did the same process about a week ago and it was fine - before the new layout for the "consent screen". Their error message don't even say what's the field with an error and their docs are out of date!

Comment: My empathy. 'Clear cache and cookies' is the closest they can say to 'factory reset your phone' on the web. It's unlikely to fix the issue, but you'll be busy logging back into all your sites and setting everything up again, so you won't bother them with your question again for a while.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding your support email to Firebase console. Go to firebase console->settings->General->Support Email->Add Email. Now while creating oAuth consent screen add same email id developer contact information as well as support email. It worked for me.

Answer (score 131):

Put the Project ID in App Name

Comment: It's weird that it actually works. Thanks.

Comment: This is worked, it seems a bug on google side.

Comment: That is the most pathetic bug I've seen in a very long time. Not only that, but it's now Nov '21 (2 and a half years later), and it's still an issue, with absolutely no indication of what the problem is. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Digging into this further, this likely only solves the issue because the name that was used was failing one of the checks for some reason. The project ID is guaranteed to be a valid application name, so this workaround will always fix the issue. I would recommend looking into the response to the request that is sent when you click to "SAVE AND CONTINUE", the response will likely contain a more descriptive error message that will guide you to fix the application name.

Comment: I have posted an explanation as an answer below.

Comment: That was weird , but it worked thanks

Comment: Worked, but seems weird.

Comment: as on june-2023, the bug is still not fixed -_- maybe they are busy updating bard AI -_-

Comment: This is weird but it works!

Comment: Still works lulz googs

Answer (score 8):

To expand on the top answer, there are numerous underlying reasons why this step of the app registration would fail. In the case where the application name is not valid (fails any of the checks that Google Cloud Platform enforces), then setting the application name to the project ID is guaranteed to fix the problem, as the project ID will always happen to be a valid application name.

It may be worth digging into the underlying validation error, which can be achieved by inspecting the network request that is sent upon submitting the form. In the "Network" tab of the Developer Tools, select the POST request that is captured after clicking the "SAVE AND CONTINUE" button. The "Response" tab (shown below for my case) should display an error object with a more descriptive message.

In my case, it seems that the application name was deemed abusive:

> The request has been classified as abusive and was not allowed to proceed.

which I suspect is because it contains the word "Google".

[image]

Comment: Same happens even for the word "Mail"

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same issue , it was because I was using "Google" in the App name.I removed it and it works for me.

Comment: it works for me, thx.

Comment: @AlekseyReshetnikov Happy to help you.

Comment: I had given the keyword "drive" in my app name. After reading your comment, I changed it. Now working. Jazakallahu khoiron :)

Comment: @Habib Always here to help

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, indeed your **App name** must be identical to your **Project ID** that you chose when creating the project

Comment: Surely this is not so. My consent form was accepted with an app name not identical to my project ID. The key requirement seemed to be that it was unique, or roughly so. Just tweak the app name a bit, and it  may solve the problem.

Comment: No, I see from zr0gravity7's answer that you are right. Indeed, we are both right.

Answer (score 2):

What @Kalind said helped me to resolve the problem.
So login to [firebase console](http://console.firebase.google.com), chose the project you are trying to create an OAuth Consent too. And then click settings-> General-> Support Email-> Add Email from dropdown.
Now when I go back to [google cloud console](http://cloud.google.com) under the Oauth consent screen, I can see that I have one registered to that project.

Answer (score 2):

This Error was come due to the project name is the same as the app name. So your app name and project name must be differnet

Answer (score 1):

to expand on the helpful post of @zr0gravity7
I checked the 'response' in the developer con{"error":

> {"code":3,"message":"com.google.apps.framework.request.BadRequestException:
> At least one field must be updated."}}

I simply changed one field, and the save now succeeded.

(This is a very disappointing design of the form error checking)

Answer (score 1):

The app name must be unique across Google. Modify the app name a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error. I was creating a project to check Google identity service. So, I named my project googleIdentityService, Then, I got the error "An error saving your app has occurred" when saving. But when I removed the word google from my project name it's surprisingly worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this everyone. I've also had the same problem for different apps and @Kalind suggestion fixes the problem. On Firebase project's settings there's a new field now called "Support email" where you can select your support email address. This will fix your issue like @Kalind and @Kasper said. I'm just adding a screenshot to make it more clear for those with the same problem.
Thanks!

[image: firebase support email field]

Answer (score 0):

For me there was an email in there already (owner of account email).
I had to invite another email > accept invite > change email > save > then change back > then I could proceed with the OAuth Consent Screen.

To change the support email on the Firebase Console you go to:
*https://console.firebase.google.com/* > select Cog > Project Settings > General tab > Support Email

Answer (score 0):

I reached this page is because of testing **Google Login**.
I faced this issue creating "**OAuth consent screen**".
But I didn't need this to create.
Just go to "**Domain verification**" page and "**Add Domain**".
There you may need to add '**txt record**' in DNS Setting to prove you owned the domain.
After adding domain, go to "**Credentials**" page.
It is ready to choose the "**Application type**" like google guide
!!! pls enjoy !!!

Answer (score 0):

I used the app Id as my App Name in the OAuth consent screen setup page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use group email from gsuite in App consent/Firebase support, you must be the group owner, and do not need that group email address on any IAM role.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the name of the application requesting access simply needs to be different from the name of the Google project.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just had another tab open with the OAuth consent screen creation in progress :see_no_evil:

Continuing in the original tab fixed the issue for me.

I did NOT need Firebase and
I did NOT need to use my project id in the app name

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using a different browser with no add ons

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).